# Error in importing jaccard_similarity_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import 'jaccard_similarity_score' from 'sklearn' package. But unable to do so. Upon running the cell in Jupyter Notebook, I get an error. I tried restarting the kernel (as mentioned in one of the posts of stackoverflow) but that didn't work for me. I've attached the the screenshot of the error:[image: This is the error that I'm getting]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the last version of sklearn, [this function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html) 'jaccard_similarity_score'   is renamed as 'jaccard_score'.

Answer (score 2):

importing has changed due to recent updates.

Instead of writing :
`from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score`

you should write :  `from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score`

note: new parameter `pos_label` is required, for example:
`jaccard_score(y_test, dt_yhat,pos_label = "PAIDOFF")`

Valid labels for `pos_label` are: `array(['COLLECTION', 'PAIDOFF'], dtype='<U10')`

References :

1. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score.html#sklearn.metrics.jaccard_score
2. https://github.com/DiamondLightSource/SuRVoS/issues/103#issuecomment-731122304

Answer (score 2):

Instead of importing `jaccard_similarity_score`, you should import `jaccard_score`. Keep in mind that *jaccard_score* needs another parameter in the arguments passed, which is **`pos_label`**.